# Wait for directory (Windows) to exist to continue code? (2.7)

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to have my code detect when a flashdrive is plugged in and then continue the code. I am currently using "os.path.exists". When I start the code with the flashdrive plugged in, the code functions fine, however, if I start when the flashdrive is unplugged, and attempt to plug it in while the code is running, the code never checks to see if the flashdrive is plugged in and keeps forcing the code to sleep. How can I get the code to work?

```
import os
import sys
import datetime
from datetime import datetime
import shutil
import time

#Wait for FlashDrive to be connected

if os.path.exists("F:\"):
    connected = 1
else:
    connected = 0

while connected == 0:
    print "..."
    time.sleep(10)

#Get current date
currentdate=datetime.now().strftime("%m-%d-%Y")
print "Photos saved: " + currentdate

#Copy and rename DCIM
src = "F:/Pictures"
dst = "C:/Users/Josh/Desktop/photos/" + currentdate
shutil.copytree(src, dst)
```

The code is supposed to be a loop and execute every time an iPhone connects and never stop running, but I cannot get the code to work if it does not really check for the flashdrive.

Comment: As a side note, your code as written is a `SyntaxError`, because that backslash at the end of your path is escaping the closing quote. When dealing with Windows paths, always use raw strings, escape backslashes, or use forward slashes instead of backward.

Comment: As another side note, instead of using `0` and `1` because they happen to be falsey and truthy, it's clearer to use `False` and `True`. And, instead of `connected == 0` (or `connected == False`), it's more readable and more robust to just check `not connected`.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is htat you set the `connected` variable outside the loop so it's never updated.

Try:

```
while not os.path.exists('F:\'):
    print("...")
    time.sleep(10)
```

--edit---

Then, wait for it to be removed at the end:

```
while os.path.exists('F:\'):
    print("...")
    time.sleep(10)
```

And, finally, wrap the entire thing in a big `while True:` so that the whole program repeats.

(Again, I do agree this is a 'hackish' and inefficent way to do this task)

Comment: Thanks, that worked; however, the goal is for the code to repeat after the rest of the code is executed and the photos and copied, but with your code the code just ends afterwards. Is there a way that I can change it so it will continue waiting for the drive to be connected again?

Comment: Edited with some improvements for that. You need to wait for disconnect, and you need to ensure that the whole program loops by wrapping it in another `while` loop.

Answer (score 2):

Cycle with some arbitrary `sleep`s isn't a good idea (at all). It makes your program less responsive to the event, because it will take at least N ms to catch an event fired at the start of the iteration*. Also it wastes CPU due to a large amount of API calls.

1. Create a window.
2. Listen to WM_DEVICECHANGE message in your message loop. It will fire every time your device configuration changed, but won't tell you, how.
3. On such event, ask for current configuration.

You can find a tutorial [here](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/detect-device-insertion.html). Also, take a look at the [similar answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6376596/python-how-to-detect-a-new-piece-of-media-in-the-cd).

(*) Actually `sleep` will test on each next system tick if `time_passed >= sleep_timeout`. If so, it will return to the program. Problem is that system tick [could be 1/18 of second](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686298%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on an old PC (56 ms), so you'll never have 10 ms delay.

Comment: This is definitely a better way to do things than the way the OP is trying to, even if it doesn't answer his direct "how can I get this code to work?" question.

Comment: This is indeed the 'right way' to wait for a device to be inserted. Constantly checking eats up CPU time and is slower to respond to changes. However, it's much more complicated.

Comment: @Murph Just thought the same and updated the answer. Nice to see it's not only mine opinion.